# How do I stop bingbot from requesting old permanently moved URLs?

Tags: 301-redirect, url-parameters, bing-webmaster-tools, bingbot

Years ago Bingbot managed to register a bunch or URLs from some bad bot trap technology that used random query parameters for honey pots e.g.

- /?c39cfn3
- /?d37hvn3
- /?28ce031

For years now we have had a regex rule returning `HTTP 301 Moved Permanently` for these requests redirecting to `/`. But Bingbot is still today requesting thousands of them every day and it seems it has no plan of stopping anytime soon. This is like 95% of all the redirect activity.

How do we once and for all stop Bingbot from continuously requesting these URLs that are permanently moved? (Without disallowing it completely or remove the root / resource from index.)

A request:

```
GET /?orneyt= HTTP/1.1
Host: ...
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
from: bingbot(at)microsoft.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko; compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm) Chrome/103.0.5060.134 Safari/537.36
X-HTTPS: 1
```

And the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: /
...
```

Comment: I've posted a related question https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/141582

Comment: @davidgo Thanks David, your question is indeed related.

Answer (score 1):

Redirects are being checked regularly, so it's not a good option.  In any case, I would start with the fundamentals, which is to check that there are no links in the content pointing out to those resources.

If those resources exist, then I would recommend using a **403 (Forbidden)** response code which declares that access is limited to them and they shouldn't do so.

If those resources don't exist, I would recommend using a **410 (Gone)** response code which declares that those resources are no longer available and that this condition is likely to be permanent.

Comment: Agreed, or even 404.

Comment: This would suggest that Bing treats a HTTP 301 as a temporary redirect (HTTP 302). I can try HTTP 410 and see if there is any reduction by time. What I am afraid of is that it's gonna affect the indexing of the root / itself.

Comment: @RohitGupta Won't a 404 encourage Bingbot to revisit the URL again?

Comment: @tim, you are correct, 410 may be the best.

Comment: I wonder if the problem is more to do with the "?" in the URL, signifying its a parameter.   What impact would a 404 or 410 have on the homepage associated with the URL.  I posit a 400 (malformed request syntax/deciptive request routing) may be more appropriate.  A 403 might also work but implies a refusal to show the content rather that this request is a client error or deceptive request routing.

Answer (score 1):

I have recceived a reply from the Microsoft engineering team:

> We use 410 and 404 as a content signal to avoid selecting such
> content in the future. It may take more than one crawls as many 404
> and 410 comes back alive.

With that said I can only say 404 and 410 seems to be the right approach. I can confirm that after switching from 301 to 410 I have a month later started to see a reduction in the number of crawled pages.

Answer (score 0):

If the redirects have been active for a year or more, the only purpose in maintaining them would be if there are still a lot of valid backlinks pointing toward the old urls.  If I was in your shoes, I'd just let them 404.